# Xamarin master detail page auto hamburger

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, master-detail, hamburger-menu

I have a Xamarin'application with master detail page and I would like to have on ios, android and uwp the hamburger icon for the menu.

Now I'm using the sample found on xamarin site to create the master detail page.

On android the icon is visible without doing anything:
[image]

On ios (and UWP) isn't visible:

[image]

Why on ios and UWP there is this behavior?
How can I have the icon on all three platform?

Thanks!

EDIT: I haven't include any image, nor for android nor for ios and UWP.

Comment: Will you please post the code you're using for your iOS and UWP views?

Comment: @JacobBarnes Hi, all my view code is in PCL solution.
Here a link with all page that compose the master page https://ufile.io/y5azo

Comment: The PCL solution should have no UI code in it as it would be impossible to share between the various devices. The PCL is meant to share code commonly used between the devices, such as a data access layer. I'm not sure what you mean when you say all the view code is in the PCL because that wouldn't work. Unless you've just stored the views in the PCL project, but if that's the case, please post that code.

Comment: Here the full code: https://ufile.io/vk61o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the codes and found that it was caused by the outer `NavigationPage`. You are currently nesting `MasterDetailPage` inside `NavigationPage`, which caused the disappearance of the toggle button.

So, the solution is easy, simply modify the following line of code in `LoginPage.xaml.cs`:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MasterDetailAppPage());
```

To this:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailAppPage();
```

**Update:**

In iOS, xamarin doesn't provide toggle button icon by default, you need to set it manually on the MasterPage. ie in `MasterDetailAppPageMaster.xaml`:

```
<ContentPage 
         ...
         Icon="hamburger.png"
         Title="{sgat:Translate appName}">
```

and add your icon image as resource into Resources folder of iOS project. but I've already seen `hamburger.png` in your project. So you can use this directly.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the reply.
With this code, UWP works but ios is the same.
https://ibb.co/eBPJFw <<-- ios
https://ibb.co/cj2ihb <<-- UWP

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the ios, you need to set the icon manually in your master page. Please check my update of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It's works, but I need to add the hamburger.png icon in all the ios format, like the application icon?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to add hamburger.png icon in all ios format, if you want your app to support all ios devices.

Comment: Thank you! 
In the Icon property of the contentPage I must set the value "hamburger.png", and in resources folder I must have the files "hamburger.png", "hamburger-60@2x.png", "hamburger-Small-40.png", etc..?

Comment: Thanks for pointing in right direction. I had to do this:
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailAppPage());